# Angular 6 disable cache busting

Tags: angular

I am using Angular 6+ and I need to disable cache busting.
That is, I don't now want my "ng --prod --aot" to result in a file with a hash. I have had no luck googling for this. Has anyone been able to do this for a prod build?

Thank you very much!

Comment: For a little more info about why exactly I want to do this, I am uploading it to an embedded device, and the framework I am using doesn't like the length of the file names. I think removing the hashes should be much easier than changing my framework :p

Comment: Did you try with `--output-hashing=none`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try with

```
   ng build -prod --output-hashing none
```

OR

```
ng build -prod --output-hashing=none
```

Below are the options you can pass in --output-hashing

1. **none**: no hashing performed
2. **media**: only add hashes to files processed via [url|file]-loaders
3. **bundles**: only add hashes to the output bundles
4. **all**: add hashes to both media and bundles

Comment: Is it possible to do this for selected files and assets?